Flutter StaggeredGridView not available on latest version of flutter_staggered_grid_view
What I'm trying to do is have a GridView with a variable/dynamic CrossAxisCount.
I have a FutureBuilder retrieving data from an API and sometimes I need to show one item per line and sometimes I need to show two items per line, depending on some item properties.
Being more specific the condition is:
if (previousItem != null && items[index].idCategory != previousItem.idCategory && items[index].isOdd).
The list of items would have around 700 items, please remember that crossAxisCount is final in most of the constructors.
I found the following code on Stackoverflow but it is not compatible with the latest version of flutter_staggered_grid_view.
I have other things on the app using version 0.6.2 of that package so I cannot use version ^0.4.0.
class Staggered extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: SafeArea(
       child: StaggeredGridView.count(
         crossAxisCount: 2,
         mainAxisSpacing: 5,
         crossAxisSpacing: 5,
         children: List.generate(14, (index){
           return Container(
             child: Center(
               child: Text("${index+1}"),
             ),
             color: Colors.blue,
           );
         }),
         staggeredTiles: buildTiles(),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 List<StaggeredTile> buildTiles(){
   return List.generate(14, (index){
     if((index+1)%7 == 0){
       return StaggeredTile.count(2, 1);
     }else{
       return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
     }
   });
 }
}

update:
the following is exactly what I'm trying to achieve using the latest version of that package.
return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                  itemCount: cards.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      width: 187,
                      height: 210,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text('$index - ${cards[index].id} - ${cards[index].idStoreCategory}',
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                    );
                  },
                  staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                    final nextItem = index < cards.length - 1 ? cards[index + 1] : null;
                    if (nextItem != null && cards[index].idStoreCategory != nextItem.idStoreCategory && index.isEven) {
                      return StaggeredTile.count(2, 1);
                    } else {
                      return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
                    }
                  },
                );```


So, you want a custom GridView widget which shows crossAxisCount dynamically based on your API response. Sometimes, single or N items in a row. So, here I wrote a sample code for you. I hope it helps you. Feel free to ask.
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:get/get.dart";

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: const Sample(),
      theme: ThemeData(),
    );
  }
}

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sample({super.key});

  @override
  State<Sample> createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  final List<List<dynamic>> items = <List<dynamic>>[
    <dynamic>["Hello"],
    <dynamic>["Hello", "World"],
    <dynamic>["Hello", "World", "Yay!"],
    <dynamic>["Hello"],
    <dynamic>["Hello", "World"],
    <dynamic>["Hello", "World", "Yay!"],
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (currentIndex != 0) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    } else {}

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: items.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: items[currentIndex].length,
            childAspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int builderIndex) {
            currentIndex = builderIndex;
            return Row(
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                items[currentIndex].length,
                (int listItemIndex) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: Get.width / items[currentIndex].length,
                    child: Text(items[currentIndex][listItemIndex]),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Preview:


The condition to show 2 or one items per line would be if (previousItem != null && items[index].idCategory != previousItem.idCategory && items[index].isOdd) {, so we would have to do something inside itemBuilder. On top of that SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount, crossAxisCount is final and we are talking about sometimes 700 items.

Sorry, I could not understand the exact situation. If you have a dynamic 2D list, N number of list (vertically) and M number of list (horizontally). Then I can help you with that as well. So, in this case, the list will be double-sided scrollable. Vertically scrollable and horizontally scrollable. The 700 items vertically and 700 items horizontally are possible in this case.

It seems like there is a slight API change that has renamed StaggeredGridView.count() into StaggeredGrid.count().
Simply omitting "View" should suffice.
